# Two jQuery instructions working in firefox and not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to call an ajax inside an loop on click of a button.
Please find my code below. the code is working in **Mozilla Firefox** without any issue. but In **Google Chrome** **Step 1** and **Step 2**, Not getting execute, it is directly going Inside each method.
My Code:

```js
    $('#button_id').click(function () {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);  /*Step 1*/
        $(this).html('<li class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Please wait..');  /*Step 2*/
        $.each(MyData, function (i, value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "myurl",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
        $(this).html('<li class="fa fa-Send"></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button_id" class="btn btn-lg btn-success warning_1 btn-block" style="border-radius: 3px;"><li class="fa fa-send" ></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit</button>
```

Comment: Instead of `$('this')` use `$(this)`. Remove the single quotes.

Comment: I tried to run your code on Chrome and didn't get any issue on the steps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)` and not `$('this')`. Single quotes should be removed:

```js
$('#button_id').click(function() {
  /*Step 1*/
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  /*Step 2*/
  $(this).html('<li class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Please wait..');
  $.each(MyData, function(i, value) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "myurl",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(result) {
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  });

  $(this).html('<li class="fa fa-Send"></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_id">Button</button>
```

Comment: Kindly share the relevant HTML too

Comment: My HTML Code:

`<button type="button"  id="button_id" class="btn btn-lg btn-success warning_1 btn-block" style="border-radius: 3px;"><li class="fa fa-send" ></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit</button>`

Comment: That doesn't help. I need to know what error are you getting in the console and what is `MyData`? Is error related to `MyData`?

Comment: I am not getting any error, The code is working in Mozilla. Only in Chrome My Step 1 and Step 2 not working.
`MyData` is an `json Object`, In each  method I am iterating the MyData

Comment: I have added a `button` in my code above. Try running this above snippet in Chrome.